# set columnGroupShow via api

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to set `columnGroupShow` via the `ColumnApi` or `GridApi` in ag-grid? My project needs to toggle the ability to hide/show a column upon expanding the column group in real-time

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **columnApi.setColumnGroupState()** function to open or close your column group:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-state/#reference-state-setColumnGroupState

to open a column group, just pass the following arguments

```
stateItems: ({ groupId: "myColumnGroupId"; open: true; })
```